# Need to learn multithreading any good books or good articles?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Eventhough I have been involved in .net for a few years I have not done multithreading in a serious way.I have used the background worker and the Dispatcher object in WPF in a very simple way.

All the jobs I would like to apply (financial sector) they all require multithreaded experience. Not sure what knowledge of threading is required but I seem to be stack without it.

Is there any books or good examples (eg. codeplex, etc) which gives an idea or what I need to know as a developer to work on *Soft real time* applications using Windows Forms or WPF?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/), by Joseph Albahari.

You can download the PDF from the page for free.

It is translated into Chinese, Czech, Persian, Russian and Japanese

It has lots of examples in C#, and I think it covers all the main topics about multithreading...

Comment: @user712923 read it and take a look at all the examples. I always use it as a reference ;)

Answer (score 6):

Joe Duffy. [Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X). [Blog](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/Default.aspx). [Period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop).

Comment: Is it still a good reading for .net 4.x world?

Answer (score 5):

[Here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) is a pretty good introduction to multithreaded C#.

Comment: I was about to link this. It's by far the best source of information on multithreading for the dotnet framework.